# Где хранить тексты песен?

Tags: android

Хочу написать программу похожую на [эту](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.shaden.kidssongs). Там отображается текст проигрываемой песни. Скажите где лучше всего хранить тексты песен? В БД, json или где-то еще?

Answer (score 1):

Лучше в БД, с обёрткой по работе с данными.

Comment: Обоснуйте пожалуйста. Может быть уточните какую именно БД топикстартеру выбрать.

Comment: не хотелось через БД делать, но видимо придется) Спасибо за ответ.

Comment: Способ хранения данных не может зависеть от типа или структуры одной сущности. Jason, дополните ваш вопрос следующим: 1) откуда в приложении будут появляться песни и текст к ним. 2) Должны ли кэшироваться песни и тексты к нимю. 3) В каком формате появляются дынне с песнями и их текстами? Может вам и хранить не понадобится

Comment: хранить все равно думаю понадобиться. Приложение должно работать оффлайн, без интернета.

Comment: В андроиде бд из коробке - sqlite. Смысла прикручивать какую-другою не вижу. Если же у вас связка с сервером, то это не к аднроиду относится. Обосновать? БД предоставляет инструментарий для работы с данными, Зачем придумывать велосипед?

Answer (score -1):

Лучше в БД, сразу подумайте какой поиск вы будете делать и как его осуществлять. Можно использовать SQLite.